# angular 4 typeahead reactive form array of JSON object

Tags: arrays, angular, object, angular-reactive-forms, typeahead

I have a form that has an input field that take a typeahead. I am getting an array of JSON object from my API call :

```
allPeople = [{"id":1,"first_name":"Abba","last_name":"Lee","current_position":"Travel Expert"}, {"id":2,"first_name":"Abbey","last_name":"Joe","current_position":"water keeper"}]
```

but when start typing I just get `[object object]`

This is what I have now :

```
<input formControlName="person" [typeahead]="allPeople" [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="10" [typeaheadMinLength]="0" type="text">
```

I tried :

```
<input formControlName="person" [typeahead]="inf as inf.first_name for inf in allPeople | filter:{first_name:$viewValue}" [resultFormatter]="formatMatches" [inputFormatter]="formatMatches"  [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="10" [typeaheadMinLength]="0" type="text">
```

But I am getting an error :

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'as' at column 5 in [inf as inf.first_name for inf in allPeople | filter:{first_name:$viewValue}] in ...
```

How can I get the input to show/suggest me the first_name and last_name when I start typing?

Comment: Which typeahead library you are using?

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is custom array so you need to specify which key you need display in typehead

```
<input [(ngModel)]="customSelected"
       [typeahead]="allPeople"
       typeaheadOptionField="first_name"
       class="form-control">
```

You need to use `typeaheadOptionField` and here you need to give key name where is value so here you have to use `first_name`

Comment: Thanks, it is working for first name. Is it possible to get the first and last name at the same time?

Comment: I think no way you can do like merge first_name and last_name in full_name key and display full_name key in typehead

Comment: Was trying that now. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help you.!